# Consumer protection laws regarding products never delivering promised features

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection

Note: this is not about any specific product, but a general pattern that I've observed.

It's alarmingly common, especially with tech-related products, to over-promise and under-deliver. Consumers buy products based on either:

- A feature which is promised to be **available in the near future** (and subsequently never added), or
- A feature which is **supposedly available now** but for some reasons not functioning properly/at all (and never fixed by the manufacturer).

What connects these two is that consumers pay for something which ultimately doesn't work. I saw the former with Apple HomeKit capability in smart-home devices, and the later with "smart" TVs.

I would like to deliberately exclude here a case where some feature is misleading/misunderstood like [Tesla's FSD](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/07/14/tesla-autopilot-self-driving-false-advertising-germany.html), as this seems completely different (feature is present and working, but its capabilities are over-advertised).

---

1. The question here is: **what protection do consumers have in such situations?**
2. Does consumer have any legal ground to challenge the manufacturer?
   Logically products which were in use for months cannot be returned to a distributor, nor should the distributor be responsible for the manufacturer's under-delivery.